# Laravel filter parent

Tags: laravel

This seems easy enough in my mind, but I think I've been at this for too long.

Structure:

```
Student
|_Bursaries
  |_Enrolments
    |_Courses

Academic Institution
|_Campus
```

An Enrolment also gets assigned a Campus.

What I'm trying to achieve is to find the enrolment that has an Academic Institution with the name 'Pearson Institute' (in this case) so that I can create a course under the found enrolment. (If no enrolment is found with such an Academic Institution, then I would create it).

```
            $student = Student::findOrFail(1); // select the student I want to work with
            $bursary = $student->bursaries()->first(); // select the first bursary
            $bursary->enrolments()->whereHas('academic_institution', function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('academic_institution','=','Pearson Institute');
            })->get(); //select the academic institution - here is where its going wrong.
```

I think I am misunderstanding/misusing whereHas?

Enrolment model:

```
class StudentBursaryEnrolment extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'academic_institution_campus_id',
    'student_number'
];

public function student () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
}

public function academic_institution () {
    return $this->hasOneThrough('App\AcademicInstitution','App\AcademicInstitutionCampus');
}

public function academic_institution_campus () {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AcademicInstitutionCampus');
}

public function courses() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentBursaryEnrolmentCourse');
}
}
```

Comment: oh hi, you again with similar question

Comment: @neel-bhanushali If this is a duplicate, please flag it as such.

Comment: @JorisJ1 it is not a duplicate. The question is different, the project is the same.

Answer (score 1):

How about this; find the institution before querying enrolments:

```
$institution = AcademicInstitution::where('academic_institution', 'Pearson Institute')
    ->first();

if (!is_null($institution)) {
    $enrolments = $bursary->enrolments()
        ->where('academic_institution', $institution->id)
        ->get();
}
```

An alternative might be a `->join()`, but the above is less complex.

---

As a side note: I find your datalayout unclear and I suggest you redesign it. For instance, is a bursary really mandatory for a student to enroll? And `StudentBursaryEnrolmentCourse` feels like it should not be a model at all but a pivot table instead.

Something like this (for a start):

- Student hasMany Bursary.
- Student hasMany Enrolment.
- Enrolment belongsTo Student.
- Student hasMany Course.
- AcademicInstitution hasMany Enrolment.
- Enrolment belongsTo AcademicInstitution.

Comment: Hi Joris, thanks for the response but this wouldnt work as you are searching for the "parents parent id" in the enrolment. The 'campus_id' gets stored with the enrolment, not the 'academic_institution_id'. Hence the difficulty I'm facing.

Comment: I see. Would you please show your table layout, including columns? It will help me reproduce your situation.

Comment: Thanks Joris, I ended up going 'direct' with a few ```IF``` statements and direct ```DB:table``` queries with joins to get the required data.